# How can I zoom in TextEdit without breaking word wrap/wrap to window?

Tags: textedit

I am using the TextEdit in the default mode i.e wrap to window mode for the rtf files.

How do I zoom in(using 2 finger zoom gesture on trackpad) to view the text without breaking the wrap-to-window feature?

Comment: would font resizing break the formatting? It might have been your first thought too I think

Comment: yes it would break formatting

Answer (score 1):

In Finder, locate the file and use quicklook <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and pinch to zoom.